# How to perform find query on react as search bar?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, mern

So basically the goal is to perform a search query of my database that based on the name of the product.

Using the `.find()` of mongo and `RegExp` i was able to successfully produce the backend get request that took  `req.body.name` and was able to find the appropriate product. Code below.

```
const searchProduct = async (req, res) => {
    const name = req.body.name
    const product =  await Product.find({ name: new RegExp(name, 'i') })

    if (!Product) {
        return res.status(400).json({error: 'enter proper search'})
    }

    res.status(200).json(product)
    
}
```

Now while using that API endpoint with react is when the problem occurs.

```
 const product = {search}

        const response = await fetch('/api/products/search', {
            body: JSON.stringify(product),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            } 
        })
```

Here  `product` is a state that I got from the search form that is sent as the `req.body.name` to be sent for the GET request from the backend.
But the error that I find is

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body
```

What surprises me is that this request works when tested with Postman or Thunder Client but not on the front end.

I am using mongo and mongoose so the question being is that is there a way to go around this problem or would I have to incorporate atlas search as a compromise.

Thanks for any help

Comment: _"Error: ..., Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body"_ That might be the cause. With a GET request you can send the search string as a request _query string_ or a _parameter_.

Comment: how would i go about implementing this

Comment: There are  posts online with similar issues, and you can search for them as "expressjs get query params" and "expressjs get query string". Also, refer the ExpressJS documentation.